# Adding two 8-Bit numbers in haskell

Tags: haskell

I was trying to define a function(s) that helped me simulate basic operations when using 8-Bit numbers.

I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible  without importing anything, so I started with two lists of 8 elements in it (which are 0's and 1's).

If I'm not mistaken it should start looking like this:

```
bitsum :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
bitsum [][] = []
```

after this last line it starts to get kind of tricky for me because I can't add one to one the elements the lists.

```
bitsum (x:xs)(y:ys)
```

that's all that I have right now that I think is correct.

My idea was to try something like this:

```
bitsum :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
bitsum [][] = []
bitsum (x:xs)[] = (x:xs)
bitsum [](y:ys) = (y:ys)
bitsum (x:xs)(y:ys) | (x:xs) == (y:ys) && < 0 = (x:xs)
                    | (x:xs) == (y:ys) && > 0 =
```

but I think I'm taking a wrong turn somewhere.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand with this problem.

Comment: Hint: The basic addition operation actually requires *3* inputs -- the 2 bits, and a carry bit.  Try defining `fullAdder x y carry`.

Comment: You'll have a slightly easier time to define a custom data type for bits instead of trying to use 0 and 1 which don't have the right behavior. Try `data Bit = Zero | One deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)`. Or, even better in some ways, just use `type Bit = Bool`.

Comment: What do you think "bitsum (x:xs)(y:ys) | (x:xs) == (y:ys) && < 0 = (x:xs)" means?  It's not legal haskell, so what are you *trying* to do with it?

Comment: Do you want to _emulate_ 8-bit numbers? There is directly accessible 8-bit arithmetics on `Word8` values in `Data.Word`.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need a carry bit.  You can't add column by column.  Let's do it piece by piece:

```
bitsum :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
bitsum = bitsum' 0
  where
    bitsum' _ [] [] = []
```

There's a start.  We start with no carry, and we deal with the case of no more bits to add.  So what if both bits are 0?

```
    bitsum' 0 (0:xs) (0:ys) = 0 : bitsum' 0 xs ys
    bitsum' 1 (0:xs) (0:ys) = 1 : bitsum' 0 xs ys
```

Okay, so if both are 0, and carry is 0, then the result for that bit is 0 and no carry.  If there is a carry use it, and continue without one.

```
    bitsum' 0 (1:xs) (1:ys) = 0 : bitsum' 1 xs ys
    bitsum' 1 (1:xs) (1:ys) = 1 : bitsum' 1 xs ys
```

If they are one, its similar.  except there will always be a carry.  And then if they are different:

```
    bitsum' 0 (x:xs) (y:ys) = 1 : bitsum' 0 xs ys
    bitsum' 1 (x:xs) (y:ys) = 0 : bitsum' 1 xs ys
```

Well they have to be 0 and 1 because we've dealt with all other cases, so they must add up to one.  You can figure out what it should be from that.  You start to see some patterns above, and so this can all be condensed to end up with a shorter answer.

```
bitsum :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
bitsum = bitsum' 0
  where
    bitsum' _ [] [] = []
    bitsum' carry (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == y = carry : bitsum' x xs ys
                                | otherwise = (1 - carry) : bitsum' carry xs ys
```

(1-carry) is a fancy way of flipping a 1 to 0 or vice versa since in that case the bit is always the opposite of the carry.

Answer (score 2):

Carries are unnecessary for this. Note two properties of bitwise binary addition: the high digit is given by AND and the low digit is given by XOR. These are:

```
xor a b = if a == b then 0 else 1

and' 1 1 = 1 -- `and` is a function in Prelude.
and' _ _ = 0
```

To find the binary sum, simply take the bitwise xor and and to find the low and high digits, respectively. Shift the high digits (left or right, depending on Endian-ness) and take the sum of that, and the low digits.

Little endian:

```
bitsum0 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
bitsum0 xs ys
    | (sum xs) == 0 = ys
    | (sum ys) == 0 = xs
    | otherwise = bitsum0 low (0:high)
        where low = zipWith xor xs ys
              high = zipWith and' xs ys
```

Big endian:

```
bitsum1 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
bitsum1 xs ys
    | (sum xs) == 0 = ys
    | (sum ys) == 0 = xs
    | otherwise = bitsum1 low ((tail high) ++ [0])
        where low = zipWith xor xs ys
              high = zipWith and' xs ys
```

The two guards in each function ensure termination ; eventually, the recursion will end up adding x+0, which is when we are finished.

Note that no error checking is done. Overflows and lists of different lengths (as well as null lists) are undefined behaviour. Your lists could be filled full of meaningless garbage (particulary, `and'` treats 0 as 0 and everything else as 1). Perhaps it would be more pragmatic to use something like

```
data Bit = Bool
type Word_8 = (Bit , Bit , Bit , Bit , Bit , Bit , Bit , Bit )
```

or better yet

```
import Data.Word
binsum :: Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8
binsum = (+)
```

Comment: Carries are indeed "unnecessary" for adding... provided you're happy to use an O(n^2) algorithm instead of the O(n) one that carries enable (and that basically all digital electronics therefore uses) :-P

Answer (score 0):

This is a super simple gate representation in Haskell.
Just began learning Haskell so the format is simple and how I'm learning.. 
Since building a bit sim in maths seemed fun, I hacked this together.. Hope it helps someone :)

```
andGate x y = [z | z <- [if (x == 1 && y == 1) then 1 else 0]]

orGate x y = [z | z <- [if (x == 1 || y == 1) then 1 else 0]]

nandGate x y = [z | q <- (andGate x y), z <- [if (q == 0) then 1 else 0 ]]

norGate x y  = [z | q <- (orGate x y), z <- [if (q == 0) then 1 else 0 ]]

xorGate x y  = [z | 
 xn <- [if (x == 0) then 1 else 0], 
 yn <- [if (y == 0) then 1 else 0],
 q  <- (andGate xn y), 
 p  <- (andGate x yn), 
 z  <- (orGate q p)]

xnorGate x y  = [z | 
 xn <- [if (x == 0) then 1 else 0], 
 yn <- [if (y == 0) then 1 else 0],
 q  <- (andGate xn yn), 
 p  <- (andGate x y), 
 z  <- (orGate q p)]

halfAdder a b = [ (x, y) | x <- (xorGate a b), y <- (andGate a b)]

fullAdder a b c = [ (sum, cout) |
 u1     <- xorGate a b,
 u2     <- andGate a b,
 sum    <- xorGate u1 c,
 u4     <- andGate u1 c,
 cout   <- orGate u4 u2]
```